# Is there a repository/collection for useful PMD XPath rules?

Tags: xpath, repository, pmd

Well, the title says it all: Is there a repository/collection for useful PMD XPath rules? I know there are PMD Java rules on the PMD page, e.g. http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/rules/java/imports.html

Is there a similar collection for PMD XPath rules?

Comment: I am also interested, so try to bring it up.

Comment: looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604905/pmd-xpath-to-suppress-atleastoneconstructor-and-unusedprivatefield