# PMD xpath to suppress AtLeastOneConstructor and UnusedPrivateField?

Tags: xpath, pmd

I have this piece of code and PMD reports two rule violations:

AbstractExceptionHandler has no constructor (AtLeastOneConstructor)

And the field uriInfo is a unused private field (UnusedPrivateField)

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AbstractExceptionHandler {  // PMD AtLeastOneConstructor warning here 

   /** the uriInfo injection. */
   @Getter
   @Context
   private UriInfo uriInfo; // PMD UnusedPrivateField warning here
```

both warnings are okay, but we use annotations to generate code. So the warning is useless for us.

We have created following suppressions:

**AtLeastOneConstructor**

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/AtLeastOneConstructor">
    <properties>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath"
            value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[//ImportDeclaration//Name[@Image='lombok.NoArgsConstructor'] | //TypeDeclaration//MarkerAnnotation//Name[@Image='NoArgsConstructor']]" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

**UnusedPrivateField**

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateField">
    <properties>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath"
            value="//ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration//FieldDeclaration[//TypeDeclaration//MarkerAnnotation//Name[@Image='Getter'] | //TypeDeclaration//MarkerAnnotation//Name[@Image='Setter']]"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

And the PMD xpath Designer tells us it is the exact used lines with the violation, but still PMD reports a error.
Can someone help me out of the dark?